# Python pandas: Nested List of Dictionary into Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

Here is how the data structure is below... It is a **List** with inner List that contains two **Dictionaries** each.

I want it into dataframe with these headings: *hasPossession, score and spread*.

> [[{'hasPossession': '0',    'score': '23',    'spread': '-0'},
>   {'hasPossession': '0',    'score': '34',    'spread': '0.0'}], 
>   [{'hasPossession': '0',    'score': '',    'spread': '-7.5'},
>   {'hasPossession': '0',    'score': '',    'spread': '7.5'}], 
>   [{'hasPossession': '0',    'score': '',    'spread': '-1'},
>   {'hasPossession': '0',    'score': '',    'spread': '1.0'}]]

Generally, above structure is a **List** that contains 3 **Lists** and each List contains 2 **Dictionary** with 2 elements.

How do I transform such into pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`flatten`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python) the list and use the [default constructor](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html)

```
pd.DataFrame([k for item in initial_list for k in item])

    hasPossession   score   spread
0   0               23      -0
1   0               34      0.0
2   0                       -7.5
3   0                       7.5
4   0                       -1
5   0                       1.0
```

Comment: RafaelC, perfect solution you got there.